# What's the correct way to implement custom claims in WIF?

Tags: wif

I'm trying to implement claims-based security in an ASP.NET MVC application. I plan on using the ClaimsPrincipalPermission class to validate access based on Resource/Operation pairs.

For example

```
 [ClaimsPrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Operation="Read", Resource="Invoices")]
 [ClaimsPrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Operation="Create", Resource="Fees")]
```

So now I need custom Claims to validate my operation/resource pairs. I have different Resources, all of which have CRUD operation.

Here's what I had in mind for a custom claim:

```
 ((ClaimsIdentity)incomingPrincipal.Identity).AddClaim(new Claim("http://mysoftware.com/identity/claims/invoices", "Read"));
```

or

```
     ((ClaimsIdentity)incomingPrincipal.Identity).AddClaim(new Claim("http://mysoftware.com/identity/claims/fees", "Create"));
         ((ClaimsIdentity)incomingPrincipal.Identity).AddClaim(new Claim("http://mysoftware.com/identity/claims/fees", "Read"));
```

So basically, one claim type per resource, and the claim values can be a combination of Read/Create/Update/Delete. Is that a correct way to implement custom claims for a system that uses CRUD rights? Should I do it differently?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the user's claims model their identity (username, email, roles, etc) and not necessarily what permissions they have. In the claims authorization manager you can do DB lookups based upon the user's identity and the resource being accessed what the permissions are and then generate the authorization result.

Also, if you're doing this in a web app, the built-in ClaimsPrincipalPermission sort of stinks because it throws an exception and what you really want in a web app is a 401, so you might consider the ResourceActionAuthorizeAttribute we have in Thinktecture IdentityModel helper library: https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel

Comment: It seems the referenced project has been deprecated. What approach do you recommend for MVC5/.net 4.6.1?